# Regex for files in a directory

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible to use a regular expression to get filenames for files matching a given pattern in a directory without having to manually loop through all the files.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could use `File.listFiles(FileFilter)`:

```
public static File[] listFilesMatching(File root, String regex) {
    if(!root.isDirectory()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(root+" is no directory.");
    }
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex); // careful: could also throw an exception!
    return root.listFiles(new FileFilter(){
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return p.matcher(file.getName()).matches();
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

So, to match files that look like: `TXT-20100505-XXXX.trx` where `XXXX` can be any four successive digits, do something like this:

```
listFilesMatching(new File("/some/path"), "XT-20100505-\\d{4}\\.trx")
```

**EDIT**

Starting with Java8 the complete 'return'-part can be written with a lamda-statement:

```
    return root.listFiles((File file) -> p.matcher(file.getName()).matches());
```

Comment: i have files in the format TXT-20100505-0000.trx where *0000* are  changing numbers. TXT-20100525-*\.trx does not evaluate. how would i get such files?

Comment: Did you mis-type `TXT-201005525-.*\.trx`? The pattern you wrote will match zero or more `-` followed by `.trx`.

Comment: thanks msw, i hadn't mistyped, my understanding was get all files with prefix `TXT-20100525` followed by any characters then `.trx`. Whats the significant or reason for having the extra `.` before `*\\`

Comment: thanks Bart K., however the number can get over 4 digits, i.e. 11111. The best would be any number of integers.

Comment: @n002213f, in that case, `"XT-20100505-\\d{4,}\\.trx"` would do.

Answer (score 1):

implement FileFilter (just requires that you override the method

```
public boolean accept(File f)
```

then, every time that you'll request the list of files, jvm will compare each file against your method. Regex cannot and shouldn't be used as java is a cross platform language and that would cause implications on different systems.

Comment: i doubt the validity of the last sentence, why would that be?

Comment: Regex is standard across all versions of Java, irrespective of the operating system, it doesn't matter if you use it.

Comment: then please tell me how would you distinguish between files and directories on unix and windows with a single regex? I understood that the question was to "get filenames for files matching a given pattern". 
This reminds me of writing Javascript that supports a few browsers at once...

Answer (score 0):

```
package regularexpression;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegularFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RegularFile();
    }

    public RegularFile() {

        String fileName = null;
        boolean bName = false;
        int iCount = 0;
        File dir = new File("C:/regularfolder");
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        System.out.println("List Of Files ::");

        for (File f : files) {

            fileName = f.getName();
            System.out.println(fileName);

            Pattern uName = Pattern.compile(".*l.zip.*");
            Matcher mUname = uName.matcher(fileName);
            bName = mUname.matches();
            if (bName) {
                iCount++;

            }
        }
        System.out.println("File Count In Folder ::" + iCount);

    }
}
```

Comment: using this code we can filter files from folder using pattern and matcher classes.

Comment: I think you should also escape the dot character before the ".zip" to "\\.zip"