# Java Regex to find particular file

Tags: java, regex

In one of my  test case I want to copy particular jar of a component from one location to another location. 
e.g when target directory has only following jars

org.test.custom.search-4.2.2-SNAPSHOT-.jar
org.test.custom.search-4.2.2-**tests**-SNAPSHOT.jar

I want to copy the org.test.custom.search-4.2.2-SNAPSHOT-.jar . Where version of this jar can be changed at any time . So I can use the regex for that purpose as mentioned here[1]. But I want to know how to omit the other jar in regex. i.e want to omit the jar which has string "**tests**" in its name.

1.[Regex for files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928680/regex-for-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: You could use something to filter files with a stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` instead of `regex` to check if the file name containing the word "tests" like this:

```
if(fileName.indexOf("tests") >= 0) {
    // do what you want
}
```

**Update:** `indexOf()` will be much quicker than a `regex`, and is probably also easier to understand.

Comment: This will filter both files at the moment. Modifying to "-tests-" would solve the problem

Comment: Sir if you see it is 'tests' not 'test'. Anyway the way I show is OK.

Comment: Where in your answer is `regex` which the question is about?

Comment: In question says: 'want to omit the jar which has string "tests" in its name' and also my answer is exactly is to solve this problem.

Comment: The title is `Java regex to find`.

Comment: Bahramdun is right. A call to `indexOf` is by far the fastest.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil well, you are right. I made a test and your solution is a millisecond faster.

Answer (score 1):

The `regex` based solution would be:

```
if (fileName.matches(".*tests.*")) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Matches the SNAPSHOT exactly with any given version number, ignoring all others (including tests-SNAPSHOT):

```
org\.test\.custom\.search-\d+\.\d+\.\d+-SNAPSHOT-\.jar
```

Answer (score -1):

One regex to match the main jar but not the test jar could be:

```
\w+-[\d.]+-(?!tests-).*\.jar
```

It has a negative matcher for the string "tests-". Note that you'll have to escape the backslashes when you put this regex into a string.